# Sending value with fireEvent

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm using the `fireEvent` from `@testing-library/react`.
I declared a react component as follows:

```
const CustomParamTest = () => {
  onButtonClick(customParam) {
    console.log(customParam);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button 
        data-testid="custom-param-button" 
        onClick={(customParam) => onButtonClick(customParam) }
      >
        Custom param
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have this test:

```
describe('basic test', () => {
  test('items should be empty', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<CustomParamTest />);

    const customButton = getByTestId('custom-param-button');
    fireEvent.click(customButton);
  });
});
```

What I want to achive is to send a custom parameter with the click event, something like this:

```
fireEvent.click(customButton, myCustomParameter);
```

I want to access the `myCustomParameter` inside my `onButtonClick` function. I could make it work as follow but I want a better solution:

I created a custom click event like this:

```
const customEvent = createEvent.click(customButton, { button: 2 });
customEvent.myCustomProp = 'customValue';
fireEvent.click(customButton, customEvent);
```

And in my component I can access this value like this:

```
onClick={(e) => console.log(e.nativeEvent.myCustomProp)}
```

I feel like there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: please try to explain what's the use-case of this. currently you have a component, which has a button with an event handler and in test-cases you're trying to pass custom parameter to it in. this situation doesn't make any sense, since when the user clicks a button, it just has the default event and not your custom paramater, so what's exactly you're trying to test?

Comment: I agree this situation doesn't make sense, this is not how an app should be tested. Still I want to change the event what the button recives to a custom object, onClick={(e) => console.log(e)} I want e here to be an object of my choice instead of an automatically generated MouseEvent.